# How do they decide what/who gets nominated at the Oscars?

Tags: film-industry, awards

I watched [Zero Dark Thirty](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1790885/) last night and I have to say, I didn't expect the movie to be nominated as one of *best pictures* of 2012. Some of the flicks I was expecting were,

- The Hobbit
- Django Unchained (nominated)
- Cloud Atlas (I'm quite disappointed it's not nominated)
- Hunger Games

So, how do they decide who gets nominated or not? Because, I can't seem to understand some of the choices since there were better movies available for the choice.

Comment: removed the biased opinion part and reopened because i think it's a good question otherwise with a great answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [**official website**](http://www.oscars.org/awards/academyawards/about/voting.html):

> **Nomination ballots are mailed to the Academy’s active members in late December** and are due back to *PricewaterhouseCoopers*, an international accounting firm, in January.
>
> Regular awards are presented for outstanding individual or collective film achievements in up to 25 categories.
>
> **Members from each of the branches vote to determine the nominees in their respective categories** – actors nominate actors, film editors nominated film editors, etc.
>
> However within the *Animated Feature Film* and *Foreign Language Film* categories, nominations are selected by vote of multi-branch screening committees.
>
> **All voting members are eligible to select the *Best Picture* nominees.**

---

[**Who are the members?**](http://www.oscars.org/academy/members/members.html)

> They are the more than 6,000 artists and professionals who bring the magic of the movies to life.
>
> [Here](http://www.oscars.org/academy/members/members.html) is a short list of individuals from each branch.

---

[**Becoming a member**](http://www.oscars.org/academy/members/invitations.html)

> - You must be a film artist or craftsperson working in one or more of the art form’s key creative areas. And your work must represent an unusually high level of quality and distinction.
> - If you are a writer, producer, or director, you should have at least two screen credits on films that reflect the Academy’s highest standards. 
>     
>   If you are an actor, you should have performed scripted roles in at least three such films.
> - Some branches *(including Art Directors, Executives, Public Relations, Visual Effects and others)* also expect new members to have worked in their fields for a certain number of years.
>
> **Most candidates begin their journey to membership by finding current members to sponsor them.**
>
> If you win the support of two or more sponsors in your (prospective) branch, your proposal will be taken up by the appropriate committees. If approved, it would then be given a final evaluation by the *Board of Governors*.
>
> Also, **you will automatically be considered for membership if you were nominated for an *Academy Award* for the previous year. (Or even better, if you won one.)**

---

[Here](http://www.deadline.com/2012/06/oscars-academy-membership-invited-176/) is a list of the 176 people that got invited to be a member **this year** (2012).

- Category 'Actors':

  [image: Actors]

Comment: it would be awesome to list the qualification here  required to become a member of the academy as well

Comment: @Dredd - I added more information

Comment: thanks, you have my +1 already, answer looks very thorough

Comment: Hah +1 for a very good objective answer to a very bad subjective question.